# Boolean indexing pandas with 'in' operator?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
dict = {'plan_id':["4H", "40", "HA", "H5", '5B'], 
    'planproduct': ["4H - MMP", "40 - STAR", "9H - STAR+PLUS", "HA - MMP", 'C4 - STAR+PLUS'], 
    'juliandat':['114', '157', '149', '142', '150']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

And say I have a some lists like:

```
starplus_id = ['47', '9H', 'H5', '5B', 'C4']
mmp_pp = ['4H - MMP', 'HA - MMP', '9K - MMP']
mmp_id = ['4H','HA','9K']
starplus_pp = ['47 - STAR+PLUS', '9H - STAR+PLUS', 'H5 - STAR+PLUS', '5B - STAR+PLUS', 'C4 - STAR+PLUS']
```

What I want is to filter out rows where if the `plan_id` value is one of the 'starplus_id' values then the `planproduct` field can't be any of the *mmp_id* values and vis e versa.
The same goes for if the `planproduct` is one of the "*starplus_pp*", the `plan_id` can't be one of the "*mmp_id*" values and vis e versa.  Also if the `plan_id` is anything other than "*starplus_id*" it's fine.  (I included the column names in code bracket and the list_names in italics).

I don't know how to do this.  I've tried using the `in` operator like:

```
df = final[((df['plan_id'] in starplus_id) & (df['planproduct'] not in mmp_pp)) & 
       ((df['plan_id'] in mmp_id) & (df['planproduct'] not in starplus_pp)) &
      ((df['planproduct'] in starplus_pp) & (df['plan_id'] not in mmp_id)) &
       ((df['planproduct'] in mmp_pp) & (df['plan_id'] not in starplus_id)) |
       (df['plan_id'] not in starplus_pp)
      ]
```

But I get

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This is the more complicated boolean indexing i've tried doing in pandas and not sure how to go about it.  The results should look like

`plan_id  planproduct    juliandate
1   4H       4H - MMP       114
2   40       40 - STAR      157
5   5B       C4 - STAR+PLUS 150`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my attempt. I modified `starplus_pp` to get rid of `whitespace,+,-` because `str.contains` method had issues capturing with the characters. This necessitated the creation of temporary columns which I get rid of at the very end with the `iloc` accessor.

#Temporary columns

```
df['planproducts']=df['planproduct'].str.replace('[-+\s]','')#Concats values to match list and escape space,+-
df['planproductsz']=df['planproduct'].str.split('-').str[0]#Extracts the first phrase in planproduct
```

## Modified list

```
starplus_id = ['47', '9H', 'H5', '5B', 'C4']
mmp_pp = ['4H - MMP', 'HA - MMP', '9K - MMP']
mmp_id = ['4H','HA','9K']
starplus_pp = ['47STARPLUS', '9HSTARPLUS', 'H5STARPLUS', '5BSTARPLUS', 'C4STARPLUS']#Modified list
```

## String construction using .join

```
sid='|'.join(starplus_id)
mp='|'.join(mmp_pp)
sp='|'.join(starplus_pp)
mid='|'.join(mmp_id)
```

## Queries

```
df2=df[~((df.plan_id.str.contains(sid))&(df.planproductsz.str.contains(mid)))]
#df2[~((df2.planproducts.str.contains(sp)&df2.plan_id.str.contains(mid)))]
df2[~((df2.planproducts.str.contains(sp)&df2.plan_id.str.contains(mid)))].iloc[:,:3:]

    plan_id planproduct     juliandat
1   4H      4H - MMP         114
2   40      40 - STAR        157
5   5B      C4 - STAR+PLUS   150
```